# Calculate price forecasts from forecasted returns

Tags: forecasting, arima, stationarity, garch, trend

I have a question which makes me so hurt.
Let's have a price time series $y_{t}$ for the same asset (for example, daily S&P 500 values) $y_{t}$
It can be trendy (trend stationary or difference stationary) or not (stationary for the first moment, for example).
Currently, I can use 2 approaches: calculate the ARFIMA-GARCH model directly for $y_{t}$ and use it for the $y_{t+h|t}$ forecasts and also for quantile forecasting or calculate returns (simple or logarithmic), calculate forecasts $r_{t+h|t}$ and quantiles via ARFIMA-GARCH models too after that calculate $y_{t+h|t}$ based on $r_{t+i|t}$ (the same for quantiles too).

If $y_{t}$ isn't a TS or DS series, this approach is fully useful (is it right?).
But what about the TS/DS type series? Should I first detrend it and after that calculate the correct model and forecasts with backward transformation?

What is the best and most correct way to forecast asset prices and quantiles for TS/DS time series using ARFIMA-GARCH models?

Please, help. Also, I would be glad to get any links to books/articles describing TS/DS series forecasting based on series returns.

Comment: You have the predicted return. You know the price to which that return corresponds. Isn’t this a straightforward finance calculation?

Comment: @Dave So, I want to be sure I'm on the right way. For example, simple trended series like  $y_{t} = a+bt + e_{t}$  with $e_{t} ~ N(0, S)$  will give me different forecasts if I do detrending first and calculate `log(.)` instead of calculation of forecasts for $log(y_{t}/y_{t-1})$. Imagime both cases we get ARMA(0,0) process. So, first approach forecast will be just a $a + b(t+1)$, but the second  not... Or where am I wrong (I can be wrong!). The same thoughts I get for DS series, but here, of course, $log(y_{t}/y_{t}$ vanish time series integration...

Comment: I would be so appreciated if you gave me any articles/books (just names, not links) where I could read deeply about forecasting non-stationary time series based on returns or something like this.

Comment: I am not following. However, if a security has a price of a hundred dollars (euros, whatever) now, and you forecast that security to have a return of $10\%$ over some time horizon, I struggle to see how you could make any consistent claim about the forecasted price at the end of that time period other than $110$. // Is your question more about how to accurately predict return than how to get the price from the return?

Comment: @Dave If I have $log(y_{t}/y_{t-1})$ as ARMA(0,0) with zero mean, I'll get constant forecast. But correct forecast will be a straight line with $b$ coefficient.